# Prevent redirect with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms

I am having a problem preventing a redirect in my code. I have a form that is loaded and then sent with AJAX. However the page is being redirected to /sent_contact/, instead of being handled with AJAX. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* --- Load Contact Form --- */

  $("#contact").load("contact_form/", function() {
    console.log("received form");
  });

  /* --- Send Contact Form --- */

  $("#contact-form").on("submit", function(event){
    console.log("submitting");
    event.preventDefault();
    sendForm($("#contact-form"));
    return false;
  });

});

function sendForm(form) {
  $.post("contact_form/", form, function() {
    // Load Confirmation
    $("#contact").load("sent_contact/", function() {
      console.log("sent successfully!")
    });
  });
}
```

The only line being printed to the console is 'received form'.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach the `submit` event to the form *after* it has been loaded, so that event hook needs to be placed in the callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact").load("contact_form/", function() {
        console.log("received form");

        $("#contact-form").on("submit", function(event){
            console.log("submitting");
            event.preventDefault();
            sendForm($("#contact-form"));
        });
    });
});

function sendForm(form) {
    $.post("contact_form/", form.serialize(), function() {
        // Load Confirmation
        $("#contact").load("sent_contact/", function() {
            console.log("sent successfully!")
        });
    });
}
```

Also note that you need to pass `form.serialize()` to the `$.post` method, not just the form itself.